# action on account shows as General Notes

Tags: lightning-experience, account, tasks, quickaction

I have created an action on accounts (Activity Log) tab below. 
The action is based on target object task.

They are all showing as General Notes in the Next Steps. 
One of the fields I have in the action is activity type. Is it possible to change General Notes to the values from the Activity Type field?

[image]

Update: I think genera notes is coming from the subject. I have removed the subject from my action, so I guess it's getting a default value. I haven't provided that default value (ie it's not showing up in my default values list). But it's ok to map the subject to Activity type (like a lookup or sth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field that is being displayed in your Lightning Activity Timeline with the content "General Notes" is indeed the Subject field on the Task object.

You can build automation to populate the Subject field with a default value of your choice. This can be done with a Predefined Field Value on the Quick Action you created.

Alternately, if you wish to copy the value of another field into the Subject, you can use Process Builder. Just configure your Process to run any time a Task is created or updated, and use a Field Update action to set the value of the Subject field to the Task Type.